# matplotlib plot() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using a Raspberry Pi to create a simple graph that shows analog readings from a potentiometer via the GPIO pins. I created a small circuit that can overcome the RPi's inability to read analog signal. There is a small problem with the plotting itself. The code I use is shown below.

```
# include RPi libraries in to Python code
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import drawnow

# instantiate GPIO as an object
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# define GPIO pins with variables a_pin and b_pin
a_pin = 18
b_pin = 23
gainF = []
gainString = 0
plt.ion()
x_axis = 0

def makeFig():
    plt.ylim(200,210)
    plt.xlim(0,100)
    plt.title('Readings')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.ylabel('Gain')
    print(gainString)
    print(x_axis)
    plt.plot(gainString, x_axis)
    plt.show()
    #plt.plot(gainString, 'ro-', label='Gain dBm')


# create discharge function for reading capacitor data
def discharge():
    GPIO.setup(a_pin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(b_pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(b_pin, False)
    time.sleep(0.005)

# create time function for capturing analog count value
def charge_time():
    GPIO.setup(b_pin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(a_pin, GPIO.OUT)
    count = 0
    GPIO.output(a_pin, True)
    while not GPIO.input(b_pin):
        count = count +1
    return count

# create analog read function for reading charging and discharging data
def analog_read():
    discharge()
    return charge_time()

# provide a loop to display analog data count value on the screen
while True:
    print(analog_read())
    gainString = analog_read()
    x_axis = x_axis + 1
    #dataArray = gainString.split(',')
    #gain = float(dataArray[0])
    #gainF.append(gain)
    makeFig()
    plt.pause(.000001)
    time.sleep(1)

    #GPIO.cleanup()
```

This code displays the increasing x axis and the y axis readings from the makeFig() function, but the graph that opens up does not display anything. It remains the same. Anything I need to change in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Can't run any of this to check, but you are only saving the most recent read? Make `gainString` (is it really a string?) a list `gainString = []` and append the read value to it in your loop `gainString.append(analog_read())`. x_axis can then just be `x_axis = range(len(gainString))`. Let me know how that goes and post a screenshot of the wrong graph if you can.

Comment: I changed the code like you instructed, its given below.

`while True:
    print(analog_read())
    #gainString = analog_read()
    gainString.append(analog_read())
    x_axis = range(len(gainString))
    #x_axis = x_axis + 1
    #dataArray = gainString.split(',')
    #gain = float(dataArray[0])
    #gainF.append(gain)
    makeFig()
    plt.pause(.000001)
    time.sleep(1)`

It created an output of an array like below

`90
[195, 189]
range(0, 2)
91
[195, 189, 96]
range(0, 3)`

which keeps going, but the graph is still empty

Comment: @KenSyme I am getting this error at the beginning of the code, does it affect the program in any way?

`analog read is 180
gainString = [183]
x_axis = [1]
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2445: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
  warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to plot a line plot of single values. This is the same as

```
plt.plot([1],[5])
```

which does not show up, because a line needs **two** points at least to become a line.

You may use a marker to display single points in case this is what you're after

```
plt.plot([1],[5], marker="o")
```